# PHP Profiles using template of /profile/name

Tags: php, api, templating, profiles

I am making a website that needs to have a profile system.

Currently i have it setup so you go to `/profile/namehere` and the profile will show with the information dynamically, BUT ofcourse you have to manually copy paste these profiles and change the name for them to work.

I want it so that when a form is submitted in this case you enter name and press submit they are added to the database which I already have done myself and a profile is automatically made.

I have researched this a little and come up with the fact that I need to make a controller or profile template that will call the information into, but i have already sort of done this, it is just i am unsure and cannot find any documentation online of how to do it specifically with **`/profile/namehere/`**

Any help would be extremely appreciated or code examples, thanks so much!

The database i am using is MYSQL although i will be migrating to PDO when i get round to it, but the profiles for now can be in MYSQL. my current page code looks something like this:

Title and meta tags are shown via config file / api.
Page content is echoed for the things being selected from database i am using `$row['var'];` with the `select` statement to access database.

At this current state a profile is copied and pasted with the name changed to the users name and that is the profile done, i want it so when you submit form to make users name it will automatically create the profile which can be accessed at `/profile/namehere/` rather than manual creation.

## Conclusion

Essentially,
- Form submitted
- User visits /profile/name
- Template is grabbed and information is called from database dynamically.
*

Comment: Some more information about your current system would help a lot, for example what database are you using, also table names to help build profile page for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You question is a bit broad. So I'll answer as mush as I can understand.

1. To access to `/profile/user`, you have to use URL-rewriting. You have to enable the `mod_rewrite` of Apache (if it's your webserver). Then you have to define rules in a `.htaccess` file.

   ```
   <IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine On
   RewriteRule ^profile/(\w+)$ profile.php?user=$1
   </IfModule>
   ```

   So, browsing to `http://host/profile/namehere` will use `profile.php` and `$_GET['user']` will be defined with `"namehere"`.
2. Display informations in `profile/namehere` page (`profile.php` untested):

   ```
   <?php
   if (!isset($_GET['user']))
   {
       // Error: Fall in error 404, or display error, or ...
       header("HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found");
       exit(0);
   }

   $username = $_GET['user'];

   // connect database using PDO
   $pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=DBNAME;host=localhost' , 'DBUSER', 'DBPASS') ;

   $sth = $pdo->prepare("select * from profile_table where username=:username") ;
   if (!$sth) { /* Error */ die ; }
   $sth->execute([':username' => $username]) ;
   $result = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ) ;
   if (!$result) { /* Error */ die ; }

   // display informations using template
   header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8") ;
   include("template.php") ;
   exit();
   ```
3. Template example :

   ```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
   <head>
       <meta charset="utf-8">
       <title><?php echo $result->name ?></title>
   </head>
   <body>
       <p><?php echo $result->info1 ?></p>
       <p><?php echo $result->info2 ?></p>
       <p><?php echo $result->info3 ?></p>
   </body>
   </html>
   ```

Comment: Fixed it, i did not have htaccess set to my var in this case name it was still set as default user which you had put.

Comment: @md5isgay Look at the source of the page, nothing ? The network panel shows an error 500 ? If so, check your Apache logs. I'm really sorry, but, it's really hard to debug your program in comments. I hope my anwser helps you to search how to start with URL rewriting.

Comment: @md5isgay Try to put a `var_dump($_GET);die;` at the begining.

Comment: @md5isgay Nice. So, move your `var_dump(...);die;` lines by line to see where the problem in thrown. Also, change in the code of my anwser `die ; ` by `die("error1") ; ` and `die("error 2");`... You have to see where the code breaks.

Comment: @md5isgay It means that your query returns no data. Check your query.